# sumar strings por medio de un bucle for en Python

Tags: python

una consulta ¿como puedo sumar `strings` mediante un bucle `for` en Python?, en mi caso particular, quiero sumar elementos consecutivos de una lista y convertirlos en un solo `string`.

```
 n=int(input("ingrese un numero))

 a[[w,e,r],[t,d,f],[e,h,j]]

 for i in range (n):
     a[1]+...+a[n]
```

Algo de ese estilo.

Comment: para qué necesitas que el usuario ingrese un número? de acuerdo a ese número será el largo del string que quieres crear según el arreglo de string que tengas?

Comment: exacto, ese numero define el largo

Comment: revisa mi respuesta, si no es lo que buscas puedes comentar ahí abajo

Answer (score 3):

En este tipo de operaciones usar generadores es una solución muy eficiente. Con esto evitamos el uso de cualquier variable intermedia, concatenación de cadenas y el uso de comparaciones que hacen el código mucho más ineficiente, además de tener que escribir mucho menos código.

Una opción es usar [`itertools.islice()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) junto a un generador que retorna los elementos de la matriz aplanada para hacer esto:

```
import itertools

n = int(input("largo del string: "))
a = [["w","e","r"],["t","d","f"],["e","h","j"]]
s = ''.join(itertools.islice((j for i in a  for j in i), n))
print(s)
```

Dado que en este caso el 'slice' sobre el generador siempre es `0:n` podemos prescindir de `itertools.islice()` y hacer simplemente:

```
n = int(input("largo del string: "))
a = [["w","e","r"],["t","d","f"],["e","h","j"]]

gen = (caracter for lista in a for caracter in lista)
s = ''.join(next(gen) for _ in range(n))

print(s)
```

**Ejemplos de salidas:**

> largo del string: 2
> we
>
> largo del string: 5
> wertd
>
> largo del string: 8
> wertdfeh
>
> largo del string: 20
> wertdfehj

Si tu lista es relativamente pequeña y tus **n** van a ser generalmente grandes con respecto a la lista de entrada la conversión a lista es más eficiente en tiempo de ejecución (no en uso de memoria) que implementar generadores:

```
res = ''.join([caracter for lista in a for caracter in lista])[:n]
```

En este caso se usa compresión de listas pero hay otras aproximaciones como la solución que propone José Hermosilla Rodrigo (ver comentario abajo de esta respuesta) usando `itertools.chain.from_iterable` o la respuesta de @Alexis que son muy buenas en cuanto a tiempo de ejecución y simplicidad de código en este supuesto (listas no excesivamente extensas con `n` relativamente grandes).

Comment: Usando `chain.from_iterable()` queda mucho más legible para mí, no sé si menos pythonico, pero: `res = ''.join(list(chain.from_iterable(x))[:length])`

Comment: @JoseHermosillaRodrigo pues es otra muy buena opción que se me ha pasado, solo que yo evitaria el uso de la conversión a lista, sobretodo si la lista de entrada es grande. De usarlo solo hay que tener cuidado con que `n` no exceda la longitud de la lista. No obstante se puede usar como sustituto de `(caracter for lista in a for caracter in lista)` sin problemas. Saludos.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, la conversión a lista es porque estaba utilizando python3 y ``chain.from_iterable`` devuelve un generator.

Comment: Vale, había entendido mal. Ahora entiendo porqué dices lo de evitar convertir a lista (para usar el generator).

Answer (score 1):

Te dejo una forma de hacerlo, tenías varios errores de sintaxis, ojo con eso.

```
n = input("largo del string: ")       # recibo el largo del string que quiera

a = [["w","e","r"],["t","d","f"],["e","h","j"]]   # la matriz de caracteres
s = "";                                           # un string vacío para después llenarlo
c = 0;                                            # un contador para restringir el largo del string que se pidió en el input de la variable n

for i in a:                 # ciclo for que tomará el valor de cada elemento de matriz a
    for j in i:             # ciclo for que tomará el valor de cada sub elemento de matriz a  (j contiene las letras )
        if c < n:           # si el contador es menor al largo que pediste
            c += 1          # +1 al contador para la siguiente iteración
            s += j          # j posee cada caracter de la matriz a, entonces lo sumo

print s                     # imprimo el string recién creado en la variable s
```

Espero haberte ayudado.

Answer (score 1):

La solución mas simple es:

```
"".join(sum(a,[]))[:n]
```

Answer (score 1):

Python es tan genial que simplifica el codigo de la siguiente manera:

```
    lista = ['p', 'y', 't', 'h', 'o', 'n']
resultado = ''.join(lista)
print(resultado)
```

La variable `resultado` esta formanda por un string que es el separador de los elementos que se encuentra en la lista que se le pasa a la funcion `join` como parametro, este codigo imprime **python** si modificas el codigo `resultado = ' '.join(lista)` el resultado sera **p y t h o n**

Answer (score 1):

Te entregare dos soluciones(Pyhon 2,7):

Primero: El operador “+” nos permite concatenar(unir) caracteres o cadenas de estos. Lo que tienes que cuidar es que todo lo vayas a unir sea un string,  ya que si intentas unir un string con un int te generara un error.

```
letras  = ["U","n","i","e","n","d","o"] #Letras que uniremos
palabra = ""                            #Variable en la cual crearemos la palabra
for letra in letras:                    #Recorreremos cada elemento del arreglo "letras"
    palabra = palabra + letra           #Concatenaremos cada letra

print palabra                           #Mostraremos la salida por pantalla
```

Segundo: El método “join” nos permite unir los caracteres o cadenas que se encuentren en un arreglo. El método nos permite dar formato a la unión. Si pruebas lo siguiente “palabra = "+".join(letras)” la salida seria: U+n+i+e+n+d+o .

```
letras  = ["U","n","i","e","n","d","o"] #Letras que uniremos
palabra = "+".join(letras)              #Uniremos el arreglo gracias al metodo join.
print palabra                           #Mostramos la salida por pantalla
```

Saludos, espero haberte ayudado.